# linking checkbox tags to another and differentiating when posting

Tags: php, html

I have the following 3 checkbox tags where each represents a category.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=1> Politics<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=2> Sports<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=3> Economics<br>
```

I need to add next to each category another checkbox that will return "1" if selected for the corresponding category.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=1> Politics
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=2> Sports
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=3> Economics
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide" value=1>
```

If I submit the above, there is no link between each catpref[] and it's corresponding worldwide checkbox. How can this be done ?

Comment: What result are you expecting from the code, once it works as you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it the same as categories

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value="1"> Politics
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value="2"> Sports
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value="3"> Economics
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide[]" value="3">
```

In your backend you will get a `worldwide` array with corresponding category value if selected, f.eg. if

```
$_POST['catpref'] = [1,2]
$_POST['worldwide'] = [2]
```

it means category 1 and 2 were selected with 2nd worldwide.